# is it safe to store deploy (read-only) github key in private repo

Tags: git, security, github, deployment, private-key

I have deploy (read-only) private key stored in Github private repo, this key can be used to clone only this repo itself.

Storing private keys in git is a bad practice almost every time, and actual key material can moved to environment variables to be rendered to the AWS user-data/etc during deploy/updates.

My question is - if the key is limited read-only to the particular repo itself, can this be considered security issue? If you cloned the repo, you already have an access and nothing extra can be gained using this deploy key.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it is not safe to store credentials in a repository.  If someone got a hold of a snapshot of your repository (if say, you left the `.git` directory of a website accessible over HTTP or someone got hold of a tarball), then an attacker could recover the key.  Now, instead of only the historical versions of the repository, the attacker can get any newer versions for the indefinite future.

I strongly recommend you not do this, since it's almost always a bad idea.  If you have any sort of security or compliance requirements on this project, storing credentials in the repository is likely to violate them.

In addition, GitHub has credential scanning.  I don't know if it computes SSH public keys from private keys, but you may find that your deploy key is automatically revoked and blacklisted once you push it into the repository.  Even if that doesn't happen now, GitHub may add support for that later and a future push could revoke the key.

The right way to do this, if you did need to store these credentials in the repository, is to store them in some encrypted form.  You can use `gpg` to encrypt them with a passphrase and there are also some project-specific secret storage techniques, such as for repositories using Chef.  You could also use a solution such as Vault if that meets your needs better.